# Cosmos DB continuation token with different queries

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, paging

When executing a Cosmos DB query, it is possible to specify a continuation token (`x-ms-continuation`). Cosmos DB doesn't seem to complain when a valid continuation token is specified with a query that differs from the original query.

What is the expected result of such a query? Or is it meaningless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> meaningless

Yes.

You've violated the API contract, so anything is possible.

Quite possibly what you'll get is the next page, as if the second query had run, but that isn't defined behaviour. When you violate the contract, anything that looks like it is working is just an accident.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Just that the API contract is nowhere specified explicitly.

Comment: @MoB. documentation  is a whole thing in itself.

Comment: @Richard Can I ask a follow up? I'm also wondering about the query used for continuation. When continuing, must I specify the same query, exactly as when the token was first generated? Or do I issue a "blank" query, then the feed just picks up the token? I use LINQ, does the order in which the query is generated matter? I send the token to the client which sends it back for next page, so server does not have state. Lot of questions, hope you can help!

Comment: @Jones: I would assume the query needs to be exactly the same (including parameter values). Depending on implementation the continuation token may not encode the details of the query on its own.